# 'sass.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: sass

I'm facing this issue in my package JSON file.

[image]

Comment: Please always post text, not images of text!

Comment: You need to install sass to use it. Either globally (`npm install -g sass`) or locally (`npm install --save sass`).

Answer (score 0):

The "script" called `start` is typed incorrectly. In this case it should be `sass <target> <source> <opts>`.

You've left out a space between `sass` and `dir`. It should look like: `sass ./path/to/your/scss etc...`

Comment: The space thing worked thanks mate

Comment: @Unknown could you mark it as correct please? :D